# how to fix this message angular observable

Tags: node.js, angular, observable

I have a little probleme, I use the node(express) and angular,
I want display all classes in angular but it's show an error like this

[image]

and it's not show json of back-end, what is wrong I don't understand

**Return of method http get clasRoutes.js**

```
res.json({ success: true, classes: postQuery, total: nbClasses });
```

[image]

**Clas.interface.ts**

```
export interface Clas {
    room: string;
    img?: string;
}
```

**Clas.service.ts**

```
  private urlGetClasses = environment.url + 'classes';

  constructor( private http: HttpClient ) { }

   getClass(): Observable<Clas[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.urlGetClasses).pipe(map(a => console.log(a)));
  }
```

**Clas.component.ts**

```
public clas: Clas[] = [];

constructor(private clasService: ClasService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.getClass().subscribe(res => {
    this.clas = res.classes
  });
}

private getClass(): Observable < Clas[] > {
  return this.clasService.getClass().pipe(tap((value) => {
    console.log(value)
  }));
}
```

**Clas.component.html**

```
<p *ngFor="let cla of clas">
   zefd {{cla.room}}
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `Clas.service.ts`. In your `getClass()` method, you are mapping to void as the return type of `console.log` is void; i.e. you are returning void whereas you've specified the return type of `getClas()` is `Observable<Clas[]>`. Therefore, you need to change your `getClas()` method to:

```
getClass(): Observable<Clas[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.urlGetClasses);
}
```

Or as Nikola mentioned, you can use `tap` to log like so:

```
private getClass(): Observable<Clas[]> {
    return this.clasService.getClass().pipe(tap((value) => {console.log(value)}));
}
```

Comment: the problem that, in my html it's display nothings

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ynnlew) StackBlitz of your issue...this is how you should be doing it. Your html doesn't display anything because you need to specify the async pipe.

Answer (score 0):

There is new RxJS syntax. You should write it as

```
  private getClass(): Observable<Clas[]> {
    return this.clasService.getClass().pipe(tap((value) => {console.log(value)}));
  }
```

make sure you import `pipe` and `tap` from `rxjs`.

Comment: what is it tap?

Comment: `import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Comment: As I can see, you've changed your initial question and now every answer here looks lame. Your new error that you got is `map` related. You used console log in `map` without returning anything. `return this.http.get(this.urlGetClasses).pipe(map(a => a));`

Comment: it's not work, i display the message of error :::                                                                                  this context of type  void is not assignable  to methods  this  of type  Observable<{}>